# How to receive events from WMR controller on Hololens2?

Tags: controller, hololens, mrtk

i am using XRSDK with MRTK2.4 and Hololens2 (2004)

I have paired a WMR controller with Hololens2 via Bluetooth.

Trying to receive Trigger event from the WMR controller.

Input Action for Trigger exists.
Controller Definition in the Mapping Profile is mapped to Trigger fine.
I have an Input Action Handler to handle "Trigger"

Are there any specific Input Data Providers I should be using?

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking to detect when the trigger is pulled? If so, this actually might be mapped to the Select input action. Try configuring your Input Action Handler to handle the "select" action instead. The "trigger" action will give you a continuous value from 0 to 1, so the input action handler might not surface that in a way you expect.

Answer (score 0):

All classes of Bluetooth device supported by HoloLens 2 supports listed in here:[Pair Bluetooth devices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/hololens/hololens-connect-devices#pair-bluetooth-devices). So, it is not possible to get input from the WMR controllers. The ability to detect them and pair them is just a byproduct of them being Bluetooth, but the HoloLens is not set up to work with them.

Could you provide more information about your business request and submit a feature request via feedback hub on new feature request to be considered in future releases of HoloLens OS and devices? If it’s a hot impacted feature, it will be possible to be given priority to jump in the development schedule.

For how to post feedback request, you can follow this doc: [Send feedback to Microsoft with the Feedback Hub app](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4021566/windows-10-send-feedback-to-microsoft-with-feedback-hub-app).

Comment: Oh you can definitely get input from a WMR controller. I fired up a scene in H2 (i wish i could remember which one), and the WMR controller joystick turned the scene around 90 degrees at a time, and the touchpad strafed the scene (similar to VR walking). Menu button opened H2 menu etc. Just struggling to find what ConfigurationProfile / Input Data Provider allowed this to work :)

Comment: You can get keys presses but not 6dof input data. So the position and direction of the controller are unavailable for you. Besides, the default behavior of Joystick will interfere with the main camera position and rotation, which is contrary to the HoloLens application design guidelines. So, in the HoloLens app, using WMR controller instead of Hand tracking is never be recommended.

Comment: If you are only interested in the behavior of button on the controller and want to handle the trigger key event in the program. Unfortunately, MRTK does not provide out-of-the-box input system profiles for allowing the WMR controller to work on HoloLens. You need to custom your own MixedRealityInputActionsProfile and MixedRealityControllerMappingProfile base on your business needs and create a csharp script to handle all Keys input.